# New records not showing in record list object page Napili Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili

I am working on setting up a Napili community and have a Community Page that includes the "Record List" component

In my lightning component I am inserting a record and when done I am using:

```
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
```

When I do so the community appears to refresh but the new record does not appear in the list of records. I have to hit the browser refresh a few times for it to show up.

The page and component are standard so there is no way for me to modify the Record List component. It has a data-aura-class of `forceCommunityRecordListStandard`

Does anyone know of a way to reliably refresh the Record List component after inserting a new sObject record? I would hate to have to add an alert that it make "Take a few minutes to show up" for this most basic request.

I have also tried:

```
    window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function () {
            $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
        })
    );
```

to no avail.

Additionally navigating to another page and back to the list view does not work either. I have to hard refresh the browser a few times or clic on the "View All" link on the list view after a few tries the record will show up.

Logging out then back in also allows the record to show up. All of this is not desirable.

Comment: What happens if you reload the window via JavaScript window.reload() or any other equivalent

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - `window.location.reload()` works but I would prefer to not have to reload the site just to show a record when it should refresh the record list component......but as a fallback I guess I could use it

Comment: The refresh view event I thought only refreshes the detail view and not list view.

Comment: How about navigateToUrl event .If you use relative path it just loads like a partial Ajax refresh

Comment: When i use navigaToURL and use '/' for the path i get to home page and when I click on navigation menu to goto Object page showing the list view it is not updated until I refresh the browser. And the docs say refreshView "which reloads all data for the view"

Answer (score 0):

Could you disable debug setting (in Dev org), **client-side component caching** and uncheck **Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance** and check again.